# Ajuda com login por SQLITE

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, login

Eu estou fazendo um *login* simples aqui via SQLite, porém na hora de apertar o botão "Entrar", fala que não existe ("*Login Failed*") sendo que está tudo correto no formulário;

```
$sqlite = "sqlite:teste.db";
$pdo = new PDO($sqlite);

$username = $_POST['login_username'];
$password = $_POST['login_password'];

$login=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email= :username AND password= :password");

$login->bindValue(":username",$username);

$login->bindValue(":password",$password);

$login->execute();

if(isset($_POST['login_btn'])){

if($login->rowCount()==1){

    echo "Logged In";

 }else{

    echo "Login Failed";
  }

}
```

Comment: Na terceira linha, coloca `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` e veja se alguma exceção é lançada.

Comment: Não Deu, por acaso não teria um outro script de login de SQLite?